# How to use Xfonts in terminal, Emacs

Tags: fonts, gnome-classic, 15.04

I just installed the xfonts-terminus package -- and now what? I'm using Gnome classic on 15.04 and this world seems to not allow the old xfonts in. Yes, I have a terminus true-type version in my .fonts, but it's garbage. I'd like to use the real xfonts version of terminus in my terminal and in Emacs.

Comment: Please add the output of `fc-match terminus` to your question.

Comment: TerminusBold.ttf: "Terminus" "Bold"

Comment: Remove the TrueType version from your `~./fonts/` and run `sudo fc-cache` or login again. What do you get now from `fc-match terminus`

Comment: That worked! A bit of a mystery how xfonts and true-type interact in gnome/ubuntu, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most modern programs use [fontconfig](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/fontconfig/) to access all sorts of fonts so you usually don't see the old-style font specifiers like `-xos4-terminus-medium-r-normal--12-120-72-72-c-60-iso10646-1` any more.

Fontconfig prefers fonts you install in `~/.fonts/` over system-wide installed ones with the same name. So in your case fontconfig used the TrueType version of Terminus in `~/.fonts`. When you removed the TrueType font fontconfig used the system-wide installed Terminus font from the `xfonts-terminus` package.